# How to "freeze" a View at the time of publishing?

Tags: nodes, datetime, views

I have a content type for publishing a node once a week (type A) - on Saturday night/Sunday morning - that needs to show, as an attachment, a list of some other nodes (type B) that go live daily during the week (one node a day)
I have a view that puts together nodes of type B for 6 days of week - Monday through Saturday, so I have a filter on Post Date between 'last Sunday' and 'now' and I limit the number of nodes to 6. Then I use Viewfield to show the view of nodes B on content type A - and it all seems to work, but! (there are always those 'buts', right??) - I want to 'freeze' the View's content at the time of publishing - so if somebody will click on the type A node two weeks from now, the list of the type B nodes should be relevant to the week the type A node was published on - so, I need to somehow filter the type B nodes view using an "external date" parameter 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I thought about the relationship angle and couldn't find one but I have been known to be blind in the past to things in front of me and instead went the `hook_views_pre_view()` route...

```
function YOUR_CUSTOM_MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {

  if ($view->name=='last_sunday_and_now') { // or whatever your View is named

    // see what we have to work with...

    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');
    drupal_set_message('<pre>Before: ' . print_r($filters, TRUE) . '</pre>');

    // here on my box it is 'date_filter' so let's change things up

    $filters['date_filter']['default_date'] = // set this to whatever you want instead of "Last Sunday"
    $filters['date_filter']['default_to_date'] = // set this to whatever you want instead of "now"

    $overrides = array();
    $overrides['filters'] = $filters;

    foreach ($overrides as $option => $value) {
      $view->display_handler->override_option($option, $value);
    }

    // let's see what we have...

    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');
    drupal_set_message('<pre>After: ' . print_r($filters, TRUE) . '</pre>');

  }

}
```

It's up to you to define the logic of what to set the dates to, but if this is sitting on a node, you can grab the post date of it via `menu_get_object()` pretty readily and then use any of the various date and time functions to create the dates.

Comment: thanks! this looks like a solid straight-forward way to do it, definitely will be my plan B: I'm still trying to solve it without code writing - with the relationships... no progress yet.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a relationship from parent node A, the `publish date` to be the filter for Nodes of type B. I think Views can handle this use-case out of the box.

So add like a  `contextual filter` for the parent node A `NID` in your View for B stuff -- and then basically keep the rest of your view listing for type B the same.

Viewfield should be able to accept an argument for the View as the `type A parent NID that was published`.

Comment: I'm at loss here...I added a relationship - Content Type B now has a Node Reference field that references Type A (is that what are you talking about?). On Content A, its Viewfield that renders the View of Nodes B, passes [node:nid], [node:created] args. But how do I add the context. filter for "parent NID"?? and BTW - I have Clean URLs on, so - not much is coming in the URL. And how do I use the A's publish date to filter on Bs? I don't see such option... can you give some more details please?